# What is the workflow of Pow(x,y) function?

Tags: c#, recursion, workflow, pow

I'm going through "sololearn" and udemy courses to try to learn C#. I am doing the challenges but could not figure out how the below code resulted with 32 (as in 32 is the correct answer here and I am trying to find out why). Can someone explain this process to me, the method calling itself is throwing me I think.

```
static double Pow(double x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0)
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return x * Pow(x, y - 1);
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    Console.Write(Pow(2, 5));
}
```

Please excuse my bad coding. I am trying to do it on mobile, which is difficult, the answer was 32. Can someone explain why?

Edit: Aplogies here is how I work through it. Pass 2 and 5 to Pow, check if `y == 0` which is false, it is now `y == 5` so `x * pow(x, y-1)` formula will be active. X is still 2, y is now 4 which means it fails the check again on whether it equals 0, this loop continues until it returns the 1.0, x has remained at 2 so `2 * 1.0 = 2` and not 32?

Comment: What exactly don´t you understand here? I hope you know what a method is, what a return-value is and a static void main? Having said this it´s pretty unclear what you have difficulties with.

Comment: You should reconsider the title of your question. A title must be a small indication of the problem you have. As it stands, it's a poor title.

Comment: If you look up "recursion", you may get "see recursion", but there are also more helpful explanations around.

Comment: This is a recursive method. Read more about recursion at [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) or just search "recursion" on the Internet, there are plenty of good resources.

Comment: Yes, the most inner call returns 1, whereby the outer call returns 2. However the next outer call then returns x * 2, which is 4 and so on, until you have 32.

Comment: Ahh thanks guys the misunderstanding is I didnt realise Pow was an existing method, I thought it was just a name assigned at random like the variables. Thank you to everyone for the patience and understanding.

Comment: @Fuss You can do this on already existing methods by overriding it with no problem. I have also included a logged version of your code step by step telling what Pow does..

Comment: @Fuss also for better questions and answers please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks again, I will have a read and work towards improving.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That method basically computes "`x` raised to the power of `y`". It does this in a *recursive* manner.

First, it defines a *base case*: anything raised to the power of 0 is 1.

Then, it defines what to do in all other cases: `x * Pow(x, y - 1)`. Assuming `y` is big, what's `x * Pow(x, y - 1)`? It's `x * x * Pow(x, y - 2)`, which in turn is `x * x * x * Pow(x, y - 3)`. See the pattern here? Eventually, you will reach the point where the second argument, `y - N`, is 0, which as we have established, is 1. At that point, how many `x *` have we got? Exactly `y`.

Let's see this in action for `Pow(2, 5)`:

```
Pow(2, 5)
2 * Pow(2, 4)
2 * 2 * Pow(2, 3)
2 * 2 * 2 * Pow(2, 2)
2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * Pow(2, 1)
2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * Pow(2, 0)
2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 1
```

Hence the result 32.

Answer (score 9):

First thing to note is that this is NOT how you would normally implement a power function. It's done this way to demonstrate recursion.

With that out the way, let's look at what happens when you call `Pow(2, 5)`:

```
Pow(x = 2, y = 5)
    -> return 2 * Pow(2, 4)
<- 2 * 16 = 32

  Pow(x = 2, y = 4)
      -> return 2 * Pow(2, 3)
  <- 2 * 8 = 16

    Pow(x = 2, y = 3)
        -> return 2 * Pow(2, 2)
    <- 2 * 4 = 8

      Pow(x = 2, y = 2)
          -> return 2 * Pow(2, 1)
      <- 2 * 2 = 4

        Pow(x = 2, y = 1)
            -> return 2 * Pow(2, 0)
        <- 2 * 1 = 2

          Pow(x = 2, y = 0)
              -> return 1 (because y == 0)
          <- 1
```

To read this representation of the recursive call stack, work your way from the top to the bottom looking at how the arguments change; then work your way back up from the bottom to the top looking at the return values (which I indicate with `<-`).

Answer (score 8):

Ok so let's go through the whole thing.

First of all, a static function is one that can be called without need to instantiate an object. There is one signature that all objects of the same class share. The double is a type within C# and its appearing here to show what the final output type of the function will be. Pow is the name of the function, double x, int y are parameters described by their type (not very well named but we'll leave that for another day)

So x is a number and y is the power of that number. There is a conditional here to check for two outcomes. If y is 0 then the answer is always 1, simple maths. Otherwise, the function performs the arithmetic using recursion (it calls itself again until it meets a terminating condition). The reason we get 32 is because 2x2x2x2x2 = 32. It is 2 to the power of 5.

I'm presuming you know what main and console.write are.

Answer (score 2):

Hello its recursion and it repeat until `y=1`, then return `2`,then return `4, 8, 16, 32` at then end. `2^5=32`

Answer (score 1):

To be able to understand each action in this recursive behavior log all the details to see what is actually going on. ***Such as :***

```
using System;
namespace Tester
{
    class test 
    {
        // What Pow actually does:
        static double logPow(double x, int y) {
            var old = x; // Hold the x
            for (var i = 0; i < y; i++){ // do it y times
                x = old * x; // Multiply with it's first self
            }
            return x;
        }
        static int counter = 0;
        static double Pow(double x, int y) {
            counter++;
            Console.Write("Recursive action[" + counter + "] Y status ["+ y +"] : ");
            if (y == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("return 1.0 = " + logPow(x, y) + " \n");
                return 1.0;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("return " + x + " * Pow(" + x + ", " + y + " - 1) = " + logPow(x,y-1) + " \n");
                return x * Pow(x, y - 1);
            }
        }
        static void Main() {
            Console.Write("Last Result : " + Pow(2, 5)); 
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives the result :

```
Recursive action[1] Y status [5] : return 2 * Pow(2, 5 - 1) = 32 
Recursive action[2] Y status [4] : return 2 * Pow(2, 4 - 1) = 16 
Recursive action[3] Y status [3] : return 2 * Pow(2, 3 - 1) = 8 
Recursive action[4] Y status [2] : return 2 * Pow(2, 2 - 1) = 4 
Recursive action[5] Y status [1] : return 2 * Pow(2, 1 - 1) = 2 
Recursive action[6] Y status [0] : return 1.0 = 2 
Last Result : 32
```

You can debug your code by looking at these details.
Also you can have fun with it using this link : https://onlinegdb.com/Bysbxat9H